# Is it possible to have report viewer in a popup window?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, reportviewer

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 web application.

The application has two new pages:

- openInvoice.aspx contains a gridview. One of the columns is ID, which is a link button and invokes "select" command. "select" passes datakeyname ID to reportviewer.
- reportviewer.aspx contains the report viewer, ObjectDatasource, and a path to the report(invoice.rdlc).

As of right now I can click ID in gridview and a redirect is done to go to the report. But what I would like to do instead is to open the reportviewer.aspx in a popup window inside of openInvoice.aspx to not have to do a redirect and force users to press the back button in the browser.

Is this possible to do? If so, How?

Comment: yes it possible why not have a go and come back here with an attempt in code if you get suck?

Comment: @ZoomVirus quite the Freudian slip there...

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Look at the anchor tag's target property.  You can also use a Modal window plugin pretty easy.

Comment: have you googled anything before posting this? there are tons of resources for popups out there. your other option is opening a new browser window to show the report. come on do some research first.

Comment: @taybriz Have I done research? I would not come here if I didn't look online first. Everything is for formview, gridview, etc. but not for reportviewer. This is exactly why I don't ask questions here, because of smug people here.

Comment: @MichaelHumelsine Thank you for your help. I'll look at Modal window since it seems to be what is needed.

Comment: @user2632193 you hadn't posted any of your attempts/fails/successes/ideas really anything so it is easy to assume you have come here expecting to have someone do the work for you. Sorry if my comment came across as "smug" but your question comes across as lazy. Really not trying to be smug.

Comment: @MichaelHumelsine That is all I needed, someone to tell me that I could use Modal or anchor tag's. I successfully used Modal and have everything working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be simple since you have a dedicated page that holds the reportviewer

I use jQuery and ColorBox.  You would just need to set the appropriate options. something like this:

```
function ViewPopUpReport(id) {
  var options = {
        iframe: true, 
        href  : null
        // there are many more parameters available, this is just the short list to keep it simple
      }
    options.href = 'reportviewer.aspx?id=' + id;

    $.colorbox(options);
}
```

Here's the kicker.  Selecting a report causes a postback.  That has to stop.  The easiest way is to disable row selection on the Gridview and substitute your own onclick (NOTE: I work in VB but you should be able to convert this easily enough):

```
Private Sub YourGridView_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles YourGridView.RowDataBound
  Dim gv As GridView = sender
  If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    Dim pkey As String = gv.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Values("your_report_id")
    If pkey IsNot Nothing Then
      e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("ViewPopupReport('{0}');", Server.UrlEncode(pkey)))
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

If disabling row selection is not an option then you can do something similar by adding an unbound template field that contains a basic html button or img icon that has it's `id` and `runat=server` attributes set so you can find the control in the RowDataBound event and then just apply the same onclick logic.  The main thing with this method is to make sure you use a control that doesn't fire a postback.

(I don't recall if leaving the gridview as selectable still fires the Select postback, if so I think it's just a matter of returning false from the view popup function or maybe a call to preventDefault or cancel bubble - it's been a while :) )

one more thing on security.  It's bad practice to send Pkeys as parameters, at the very least, if you must pass the parameter this way, it should be encrypted.  A better alternative is a session variable.  I'll leave it to you.  Good Luck.